# How to include stl file format in website

Tags: javascript, three.js

Anyone know how do create a website that can display the slt file format. And it can be resizing and rotating using mouse?

i have did some studies from [here](https://github.com/tonylukasavage/jsstl) (manu.ninja) and [here](https://manu.ninja/webgl-3d-model-viewer-using-three-js) (jsstl). i tried to use the controls from manu.ninja and put in jsstl to make it re-sizable and rotatable like manu.ninja (have to change controls.enableZoom = true).

Thank you very much.

Comment: There is an example of an STL viewer included in the three.js distribution (https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_stl.html). If you have any problems implementing this, you need to be very specific as to what these problems are (and ask them one problem at the time).

Comment: Thank you very much. I solve it by remove mesh.rotation.set( - Math.PI / 2, 0, 0 ); and add in the orbit control.